# Pesquisar tupla em um array

Tags: python-3.x, arraylist

Possuo os seguinte vetores:

```
a = [('FI', 'SE'), ('SE', 'DK'), ('DK', 'DE'), ('DE', 'PL'), ('PL', 'BY')]

b = [['NL', 'DK', 0], ['NL', 'DE', 0], ['NL', 'BE', 0], ['FI', 'SE', 0.054]]
```

Preciso percorrer o vetor **a** e localizá-lo no vetor **b**.

Minha saída tem que retornar:

```
c = ['FI', 'SE', 0.054]
```

Como posso fazer isso?

Grato pela ajuda.

Comment: As duas listas vão ter sempre a mesma quantidade de sublistas? Se a tem a tem 5 sublistas então b também tem? Ou pode ser diferente?

Comment: Elas podem ter tamanhos diferentes @Miguel.

Comment: Como é a busca? Procuras por `(FI, SE)` é isso?

Comment: Exatamente @Miguel! Eu procuro por (FI, SE), porém o retorno será ['FI', 'SE', 0.054], conforme está em b.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Podes tentar assim:

```
a = [('FI', 'SE'), ('SE', 'DK'), ('DK', 'DE'), ('DE', 'PL'), ('PL', 'BY')]
b = [['NL', 'DK', 0], ['NL', 'DE', 0], ['NL', 'BE', 0], ['FI', 'SE', 0.054]]

search1, search2 = ('FI', 'SE')
for val1, val2, val3 in b:
  if((val1, val2) == (search1, search2)):
    print(val1, val2, val3) # FI SE 0.054
    break
else: # caso nao haja break e porque nao foi encontrado
  print('não foi encontrado')
```

[DEMONSTRAÇÃO](https://repl.it/repls/StormyWealthyPetabyte)

Se quiseres localizar todos os elementos de `a` em `b`, podes:

```
a = [('FI', 'SE'), ('SE', 'DK'), ('DK', 'DE'), ('DE', 'PL'), ('PL', 'BY')]
b = [['NL', 'DK', 0], ['NL', 'DE', 0], ['NL', 'BE', 0], ['DE', 'PL', 0], ['FI', 'SE', 0.054]]

founds = []
for val1, val2, val3 in b:
  if((val1, val2) in a):
   founds.append([val1, val2, val3])
print(founds) # [['DE', 'PL', 0], ['FI', 'SE', 0.054]]
```

[DEMONSTRAÇÃO](https://repl.it/repls/SpecificVirtualSlash)

Ou:

```
a = [('FI', 'SE'), ('SE', 'DK'), ('DK', 'DE'), ('DE', 'PL'), ('PL', 'BY')]
b = [['NL', 'DK', 0], ['NL', 'DE', 0], ['NL', 'BE', 0], ['DE', 'PL', 0], ['FI', 'SE', 0.054]]

founds = [[v[0], v[1], v[2]] for v in b if (v[0], v[1]) in a]
print(founds) # [['DE', 'PL', 0], ['FI', 'SE', 0.054]]
```

Comment: Muito Obrigado @Miguel. Funciona perfeitamente!

Comment: De nada @Danilo

Answer (score 2):

Se, em vez de uma lista de listas, você puder carregar `b` como um dicionário (ou transformar `b` em um dicionário `bd`, como eu fiz no exemplo abaixo) o código pode ficar mais intuitivo, bastando um `bd.get` para localizar o valor necessário. Ex.:

```
a = [('FI', 'SE'), ('SE', 'DK'), ('DK', 'DE'), ('DE', 'PL'), ('PL', 'BY')]
b = [['NL', 'DK', 0], ['NL', 'DE', 0], ['NL', 'BE', 0], ['FI', 'SE', 0.054]]

bd = dict(((x, y), z) for x, y, z in b)
print(bd)
# saída: {('FI', 'SE'): 0.054, ('NL', 'BE'): 0, ('NL', 'DE'): 0, ('NL', 'DK'): 0}

c = [(i, bd.get(i)) for i in a if i in bd]    
print(c)
# saída: [(('FI', 'SE'), 0.054)]
```

Comment: @Miguel, na verdade esse código é muito mais rápido que o que você propôs, mesmo adicionando o tempo de conversão de `b` para um dicionário, pois o operador `in` em dicts é O(1), enquanto em listas e tuplas é O(n).

Comment: Com datasets pequenos a diferença é irrisória (milissegundos a favor do método A, sem dicionário), mas com datasets grandes a diferença é de ordens de grandeza a favor do método com dicionário: https://repl.it/repls/WorthlessAustereRegression

Comment: @Miguel Faz parte do aprendizado, para todos. :) Não precisava apagar os comentários, poderiam ser úteis para outras pessoas que tivessem a mesma dúvida sobre as abordagens.

Comment: Já estava muito bagunçado aqui

Answer (score 1):

Veja se isso te ajuda:

```
a = [('FI', 'SE'), ('SE', 'DK'), ('DK', 'DE'), ('DE', 'PL'), ('PL', 'BY')]

b = [['NL', 'DK', 0], ['NL', 'DE', 0], ['NL', 'BE', 0], ['FI', 'SE', 0.054]]

result = []
for x in a:
    for z in b:
        if len(list(set(x) - set(z))) == 0:
            result.append(z)

print(result) # [['FI', 'SE', 0.054]]
```

No exemplo eu percorro as 2 listas e verifico diferença entre os elementos para obter o resultado que você espera, e depois adicionar à lista `result`.

OBS.: Estou iniciando os estudos em python, então desculpe qualquer coisa.

Comment: Muito Obrigado @JuniorNunes sua solução também me atende! (+1)

Comment: Essa abordagem tem o problema de considerar que ('FI', 'SE') == ('SE', 'FI'), devido ao uso de sets. Além disso, a conversão + operação com conjuntos a cada item deixa o código super lento (2 minutos para comparar duas listas com 10.000 itens cada).

Comment: Obrigado pela observação @hdiogenes!